# Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

How can I find the value of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!}$?
for example for $n=6$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^6}{k!}=203e.$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought it might be useful to add the derivation of the formula given in Casteels answer.

The defining equation for [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is
$$
\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
k^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{j}\binom{k}{j}\,j!\tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{k!}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{j}\binom{k}{j}\frac{j!}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{j}\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac1{(k-j)!}\\
&=e\sum_{j=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{j}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
It is worth noting that the [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Summation_formulas) are
$$
B_n=\sum_{j=0}^n\stirtwo{n}{j}\tag{3}
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{k!}=e\,B_n\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Nice question! It was listed as related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/502676/13854), which I answered a while ago. It got some attention recently and so I took a look at some of the related questions.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is $eB_n$, where $B_n$ is the $n$th [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers). This is known as [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).