# Sums with nested radicals related to $1/\pi^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, radicals, closed-form, nested-radicals

**Context:**
I evaluated some sums related to $1/\pi^{2}$ that for a reason I don't know I can't find in the literature.

$$(1)\hspace{.5cm}{1\over 2\sqrt{2}}+{1\over 2^{3}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}+{1\over 2^{5}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}+\cdots=1-{8\over \pi^{2}},$$

$$(2)\hspace{.5cm}{1/4\over 2+\sqrt{3}}+{1/16\over 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}+{1/64\over 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}+\cdots=1-{9\over \pi^{2}},$$
$$(3)\hspace{.5cm}{1/4\over 2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}+{1/16\over 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}+{1/64\over 2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}+\cdots={1+\varphi}-{25\over \pi^{2}},$$
where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

Note that this series are related to Viète's formulas.

**Question:**
Do you know any reference where these formulas are shown? Can you prove them with a general result?

Comment: How did you "evaluate" these sums?

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm still waiting for an answer to some references to this sums if there exists. After this I will post the answer with full details.

Comment: All series should be telescoping sum. For $(2)$ and $(3)$, they can be solved using identity $\frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} - \frac{1}{4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{1}{4\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{1}{2+2\cos(\theta)}$. Havn't figure out the correct decomposition for $(1)$...

Comment: @achille hui Excellent remark ! Do you intend to give a full answer ?

Comment: I don't see how this series can be related to Viète's formulas. Please, write down the "answer" you intended to give ; even if it isn't complete, it will be fruitful for the community, just as the  very interesting track given by achille hui above.

Comment: @JeanMarie probably not, still stuck on $(1)$...

Comment: @achillehui you are right, the three sums are telescopic, but they can be deduced from a general formula (the hint: Viète's formulas) should be useful.

Comment: Please stop modifying your post after it has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

I will consider here only the third series with $\varphi$ the golden ratio.

I will establish it as an application of the following identity, justifying the presence of a $\frac{1}{\pi^2}$ term :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n\cos^2\frac{x}{2^n}}=\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac1{x^2}$$

Its proof by different means is given in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502676/305862). Among them, one finds a proof using Viète's formulas...

Indeed, taking $x=\frac{\pi}{5}$ in (1), one gets, in the RHS :

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{5}}-\frac{25}{\pi^2}=\frac{4}{3-\pi}-\frac{25}{\pi^2}$$

On the LHS, detailing the first terms :

$$\color{red}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{4\cos^2\frac{\pi}{5 \times 2}}}_{= \ \frac{1}{2+\varphi}}}+\frac{1}{4^2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{5 \times 2^2}}+\frac{1}{4^3\cos^2\frac{\pi}{5 \times 2^3}}+\cdots$$

Why is the first term highlighted ? Because it is the single term which is not present in the series you have given. All the other terms are exactly the right ones :

Indeed, one can verify that :

$$4 \cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{5.2^k}\right)=\begin{cases}2+\varphi&(k=1)\\ 2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}&(k=2)\\2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}&(k=3)\\ \cdots \end{cases}$$

due to relationship :

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5.2^{k+1}}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5.2^{k}}\right)\right) \iff $$

$$4\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5.2^{k+1}}\right)\right)^2=2+2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5.2^{k}}\right) $$

It remains for completing the proof to subtract to the RHS the "added term" :

$$\frac{4}{3-\pi}-\frac{25}{\pi^2}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{2+\varphi}}=1+\varphi-\frac{25}{\pi^2}$$

as desired (using relationshup $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$, etc.).

**Remark** : the different special values such as $\sin \frac{\pi}{5}$, etc. can be found for example [here](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html).

Comment: (1) , (2) and (3) follow from first formula, just reindexing. Have you seen them written in classical form?

Comment: May I ask you what you mean by "classical form" ?

Comment: Without sigma notation. Writing the terms explicitly.